# Here Android SDK OffscreenRenderer MapOverlay not shown

Tags: android, here-api

I use Android Here SDK and OffscreenRenderer to render map instance.

I want to draw custom bubble view with MapOverlay. For map that rendered normally (with mapFragment inside Activity) I can add MapOverlay object how described at the manual:

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("TEST");
myMap.addMapOverlay(new MapOverlay(button, destination));
```

For mapFragment this works well, but for OffscreenRenderer I don't see button at map. I tried different views, inflated layouts and simple button code above - all seems to work with regular map, but not with OffscreenRenderer. Does this feature available at the SDK? How can I make it appear?

**UPDATED:** addMapOverlay returns true.
**UPDATED 2:**

Post working code sample for suggested solution. We need to take screen-shot from view (view-shot =) and make MapMarker from it.

```
public MapMarker makeTargetSmallBubbleMarker(Route route, Address address) {
    // obtain view
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_bubble_small, null);

    // get the value..
    String destination = "";

    // inflate value into view sub fields
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.destination)).setText(destination);

    // if you use 9-patch bubble with donwside arrow for background of your marker
    // you need to change anchor point of the marker, so that the arrow will point to location
    // instead of bubble appears above the destination

    // maybe someone knows a better solution..? Calculate rendered view size
    v.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    int width = v.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    // make view screen-shot
    Image bubbleImg = new Image();
    bubbleImg.setBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(v, width, height));

    MapMarker bubble = new MapMarker(route.getDestination(), bubbleImg);
    // here, I want my bubble arrow and whole marker get a 20% offset for down arrow
    bubble.setAnchorPoint(new PointF(width / 2f, height * 1.2f));

    return bubble;
}


private static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    //v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.layout(0, 0, width, height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MapOverlays use Android views so they do not work via the offscreen renderer.

Please fallback to regular MapMarkers in this case. You can inflate and render an Android View into a bitmap and use that as the texture for the marker.

Comment: Yes, thats worked. I updated my question with code sample that now works as you suggested.